# Android Passing data with bundle (Client-Server)

Tags: android, bundle

Let me explain short description of the app to make you easy to understand my question.

Users can save name of an item, description of an item and photo.
And it saves in the app and also send it to the server side of DB.
On the app, there is list view that shows saved items.
On the layout of each item, there is edit button to correct name or description or image.
If users click one of the item they save, displays the information of the item they saved before. 
And now, I want to move the edit button from the layout of the item on the listview to view page.

I modified some code, but, when I click edit button on the view page, and if I save it, it saves on the app properly.

But the problem is that it doesn't send it to server side!..
I think there is passing data problem..

Here is my code.

ViewWishlist.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_wishlist);
    setUpViews();

    //Edit Button Click Event
    editBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.edit);
    editBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(ViewWishlist.this, AddEditWishlists.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);          

            Bundle current_item = new Bundle();

            current_item.putInt("id", id);
            current_item.putString("name", name.getText().toString());
            current_item.putString("note", note.getText().toString());
            current_item.putByteArray("blob", image);

            intent.putExtras(current_item);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

}


public void setUpViews() {

    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputname);
    note = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.inputnote);
    photo = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.inputphoto);

    // When a photo is clicked, this event would be implemented
    photo.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener(){
        // Display bigger images 
        //send byte array data with bundle to "view_photo.java" 
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(ViewWishlist.this, view_photo.class);
            Bundle current_photo = new Bundle();
            current_photo.putByteArray("blob", image);
            intent.putExtras(current_photo);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }); 

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    // Get the data from the sent Bundle from CustomWishlistsAdapter.java
    if (extras != null) {
        id=extras.getInt("id");
        name.setText(extras.getString("name"));
        note.setText(extras.getString("note"));
        image = extras.getByteArray("blob");

        if (image != null) {
            if (image.length > 3) {
                photo.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image,0,image.length));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

AddEditWishlist.java

```
public class AddEditWishlists extends Activity {


// Client-Server - Start //////////////////////
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// url to create new product http://192.168.1.28/android_connect/create_product.php
private static String url_create_product = "http://192.168.3.9/android_connect/create_product.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
// Client-Server - End //////////////////////


//Define Variables
private EditText inputname;
private EditText inputnote;
private Button upload;
private Bitmap yourSelectedImage;
private ImageView inputphoto;
private Button save;
private int id;
private byte[] blob=null;
byte[] image=null;


/**
 * Show the layout when this class is started
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_wishlist);
    setUpViews();
}

/**
 * Implemented when users click the one of the item on the wishlist
 */
private void setUpViews() {

    inputname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputname);
    inputnote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputnote);
    inputphoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.inputphoto); 

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        id=extras.getInt("id");
        inputname.setText(extras.getString("name"));
        inputnote.setText(extras.getString("note"));

        image = extras.getByteArray("blob");    


        if (image != null) {
            if (image.length > 3) {
                inputphoto.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image,0,image.length));
            }
        }       
    }



    //Image Upload Button
    upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);
    upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });




    // Save the data
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        /**
         * This event is implemented when users save the data
         */
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (inputname.getText().length() != 0) {
                AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask = new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {                     
                        saveItem();
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
                        finish();
                    }
                };

                saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null);

            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        AddEditWishlists.this);
                alert.setTitle("Error In Save Wish List");
                alert.setMessage("You need to Enter Name of the Product");
                alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                alert.show();
            }
        }
    });
}


/** If users save data, this method would be implemented.
 *  Data would be saved in the android database. 
 *  And also, these data would be sent to the serverDB using HTTP post request with JSON packet. 
 */
private void saveItem() {

    if(yourSelectedImage!=null){
        ByteArrayOutputStream outStr = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        yourSelectedImage.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStr);
        blob = outStr.toByteArray();

        //Client-Server


        // Client-Server - Start //////////////////////////////////////
        String name = inputname.getText().toString();
        String description = inputnote.getText().toString();
        // Encode the image file to String !! by using Base64
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(blob, Base64.DEFAULT);


        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));
        params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("photo",encodedImage));

        Log.v("log_tag", System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");


        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product, "POST", params1);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);


            Log.v("log_tag", "In the try Loop" );

            if (success == 1) {
                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    else{blob=image;}

    // Change Text type to string type to save in the DB
    SQLiteConnector sqlCon = new SQLiteConnector(this);

    if (getIntent().getExtras() == null) {
        sqlCon.insertWishlist(inputname.getText().toString(), inputnote.getText().toString(), blob);
    }

    else {
        sqlCon.updateWishlist(id, inputname.getText().toString(), inputnote.getText().toString(), blob);
    }


}
```

The data should pass to "private void saveItem()" on the AddEditWishlist.java
But, there is no passed data..

How can I fix it?

Comment: Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); change to Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();

Comment: You mean in the setUpViews() method in AddEditWishlists.java?

Comment: Very Very wierd...same problem. In the app DB, it changes..but nothing happen on the server side..

Comment: then check your passing value in first activity.. is it ok or not.

Comment: do i need to add "this" on here also "if (getIntent().getExtras() == null)"